# How can i use the CURSOR by using loop to set the local variables in making a function in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql database. In that I have created a function .In that function I am setting a local variable. I am using a CURSOR in this as I have to fetch the records from the table.

Based on the fetched records the function is returning the real datatype from the if condition there.

Please explain me the steps by steps to how to create a for loop in cursor in mysql function?
My code is like :-

```
  DELIMITER $$;
  CREATE FUNCTION score_exam (e integer)
  RETURNS real
  BEGIN
  Declare t float ;
  Declare c float;
  Declare d int;
  Declare e int;
  Declare f int;
  Declare g int;
  Declare h int;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE r CURSOR FOR SELECT num, quen_n,  cha_nu, sele_anr, cor_ans FROM  equestion WHERE exm_nm = e;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    set t=0.0;
      set c=0.0;
    OPEN r;
  read_loop: LOOP
FETCH r INTO d,e,f,g,h;
 IF done THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
  END IF;
 set t = t + 1.0;
  IF g = h THEN
  set  c = c + 1.0;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
   IF t > 0.0 THEN
    RETURN c/t;
ELSE
    RETURN 0.0;
END IF;
 CLOSE r;
END $$
```

If anyone would help me out, I will be greatful to him.

Comment: Put some code, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you are trying to do is get a score based on an e-Question(Exam).  Looking for total questions for the test and how many correct answers...  If no questions offered for an exam, just return 0 to prevent divide by zero error.  That said, it looks like you are going through way too much hoops to write such a complex function which can be done in a single query.. Also, you have an incoming parameter of "e" for the exam to be computed, yet do a fetch of "quen_n" into e which will screw up your fetching won't it?  I would rename the parameter just for clarification.  Your query of extra elements doesn't even appear to be used, and interpreting as "num" is a row number or pk id in the table, Quen_n is a question number from the exam, etc...  The only thing you care about is how many questions were there and how many correct...  So, here's the query I would write and just get the answer.

```
SELECT 
      count(*) as TotalQuestions,
      sum( if( sele_anr = cor_ans, 1, 0 )) as CorrectAnswers
   FROM
      equestion 
   WHERE 
      exm_nm = ExamToScore
```

Have this as your fetch, and return from that.  If no record returned from the result, return 0... if one record returned, just do the division and return that.